# issues with devicehelper.vb

Tags: vb.net

does anyone know why i get the error "DirectCast(err, SetupApiError) = InWow64 {-536870347}" when running the code below? i get this error when it calls the SetupDiCallClassInstaller method on the line: Case SetupApiError.NoAssociatedClass To SetupApiError.OnlyValidateViaAuthenticode

```
Throw New Win32Exception("SetupAPI error: " & DirectCast(err, SetupApiError).ToString)

Dim result As Boolean = SetupDiSetClassInstallParams(handle, diData, params, Marshal.SizeOf(params))
    If result = False Then Throw New Win32Exception
    result = SetupDiCallClassInstaller(DiFunction.PropertyChange, handle, diData)
    If result = False Then
        Dim err As Integer = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error
        Select Case err
            Case Is = SetupApiError.NotDisableable
                Throw New ArgumentException("That device can't be disabled! Look in the device manager!")
            Case SetupApiError.NoAssociatedClass To SetupApiError.OnlyValidateViaAuthenticode
                Throw New Win32Exception("SetupAPI error: " & DirectCast(err, SetupApiError).ToString)
            Case Else
                Throw New Win32Exception
        End Select
    End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unhappy that you are calling SetupDiCallClassInstaller() from a 32-bit process running on the 64-bit version of Windows.  That's easy to fix in a managed program.  Right-click your EXE project, Properties, Compile tab, scroll down, Advanced Compile Options button.  Change the Target CPU setting from x86 to AnyCPU.

Comment: I've tried this, now I'm getting an error about odbc connection such as "ex = {"ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified"}"... which my connection string is: Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};dbq=pathofdatabase/test.mdb;uid=admin;pwd=" ... my connection string works fine when setting the CPU setting to x86.

Comment: Bummer, there is no 64-bit provider for the ancient Jet dbase engine.  You can't have it both ways.